# "Mutual" package import in Golang

Tags: import, go, package

Is it possible to do something like a "mutual" package import in Golang?

Lets say for example I have two packages, A and B with functions AFunc and BFunc, BFunc2

```
package A
import "B"

func AFunc() {
    //do stuff but also use
    B.BFunc()
}
```

-

```
package B
import "A"

func BFunc() {
    //do foo
}

func BFunc2() {
    //do different stuff but also use
    A.AFunc()
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this without using a third package as "bridge"?

Edit:
To clarify the question a bit, this is of course not possible by "simply doing" it since the compiler will throw an `import cycle not allowed` error. The question is, is there a cleaner or more established way of working around this problem then building a "bridge package"?

Comment: No, cyclic imports are forbidden.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[interface](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types) should be an obvious answer: as long as both packages propose interfaces with a common set of functions, it allows for:

- `packageB` to use functions from `A` (`import A`)
- `packageA` to call functions from `B` without having to `import B`: all it need to be passed `B` instances which implements an interface defined in `A`: those instances will be views as `A` object.
  In that sense, `packageA` ignores the existence of `packageB`.

This is also illustrated in the comment of "[Cyclic dependencies and interfaces in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380333/cyclic-dependencies-and-interfaces-in-golang#comment30438237_20380333)".

> If package `X` accepts/stores/calls methods on/returns types defined package `Y`, but doesn't actually access `Y`'s (non-method) functions or variables directly, `X` can use an interface that the type in `Y` satisfies rather than actually importing `Y`.
>
> avoiding dependencies with interfaces in general, you can see how, say, the [`io` module](http://golang.org/pkg/io/) doesn't depend on [`os`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/) for the [File class](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) even though its functions can work on `Files`. (It just defines [`io.Writer`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer), etc., and [`*os.File` satisfies those interfaces](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Write).)

For instance, `io` accepts a 'Writer' in its [`Copy()` function](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) (which can be a File or another else knowing how to write), and ignores completely `os`(.File)