# How to avoid "import cycle" in a n--n relationship

Tags: go

A role has many accounts and an account has many roles.

How to simulate that avoiding the import cycle?

Inside my $GOROOT

```
sandbox/
├── hello-world.go
├── orm
│   ├── main
│   │   └── main.go
│   └── model
│       ├── account
│       │   └── account.go
│       └── role
│           └── role.go
```

cat sandbox/orm/main/main.go

```
package main

import (
    "sandbox/orm/model/account"
)

func main() {

    a := account.Account
}
```

cat sandbox/orm/model/account/account.go

```
package account

import (
    "sandbox/orm/model/role"
)

type Account struct {
    id    int
    roles []role.Role
}
```

cat sandbox/orm/model/role/role.go

```
package role

import (
    "sandbox/orm/model/account"
)

type Account struct {
    id    int
    roles []role.Role
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is addressed in "[Cyclic dependencies and interfaces in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20394211/6309)", in particular:

> Replace import-requiring object types in APIs with **basic types and interface**.

Or put them in the same package.

I showed an example in "[“Mutual” package import in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24527651/6309)".